# about how to get the text value when upload file with jquery form plugin

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I try to upload file with jquery form plugin asynchronous, this is my source code:

js Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').ajaxForm(); 
});
```

Html code:

```
<form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_do.jsp" method="post">
<input name="testName" type="text">
<input name="myFile" type="file">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

But,I can not get the value of testName in jsp file:

```
String testName= request.getParameter("testName");
```

if i delete the attribute enctype and remove the file input named 'myFile',so i could get the value of testName as usual,like this:

```
<form name="form1" action="upload_do.jsp" method="post">
<input name="testName" type="text">

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

how to resolve such a problem?

Comment: How about closing the form with `</form>`?

Comment: oh,it is missing, the edit plugin didn't format it, But my problem is not caused by it.

Comment: @user1665126, according to the [faq](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#faq), it doesn't seem like you're doing anything wrong.  It says it supports also file uploading, so logically, the problem must be something you're not mentioning.

Comment: do you think the jquery form plugin does not support both file uploading and text value submiting??

Comment: @user1665126, no, I think there's something else that you're not mentioning that is at the heart of the problem.  There is no reason why this shouldn't work under normal circumstances.

Comment: but it is all my code here,I have no such more avalid code offer to you, I really can not understand this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As your enctype is 'multipart/form-data', the server will not parse your request parameters. It is upto the developer to parse the inputstream & pull the relevant paramters.

Usually the apache commons fileupload library is used for this purpose(http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

Comment: Have a look at http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html ... basically you have to download and add this library to ur lib folder. then first check if its a multipart request using this line "boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);"... if true, then parse as shown in the link...